# Validation of sum of attributes from has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

With the following Ruby on Rails model "Foo":

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :bars

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars

  def bar_value_total
    self.bars.sum(:value) #TODO: must verify this is in range (0.0 .. 100.0)
  end

end
```

And Bar as a simple model with a single value attribute:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :value, :inclusion => { :in => 0.0..100.0 }, :presence => true

end
```

How can I add a validation to prevent saving Foo if the values within the total Bars is not within the specified range (0.0 .. 100.0)?

For example, if Foo has three Bars with values of 40.0 and 50.0, a Save attempt should fail when a third Bar is added with anything over 10.0.

And if a Foo already has a Bar with a value of 100.0, a Save attempt should fail if a Bar is added with any value over 0.0.

---

Update:
I added a custom validation to the Bar model (and it works)... but it seems a bit kludgy.  Is there a better "Rails way" than this?

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :value, :inclusion => { :in => 0.0..100.0 }, :presence => true
  validate :bar_totals_are_within_range

private
  def bar_totals_are_within_range
    if !self.foo.bar_value_total + self.value - self.value_was).between?(0.0, 100.0)
      errors.add(:base, "Total bar value exceeded")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Do a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).

Comment: I added a custom validation but it seems a bit dirty.  Was wondering if there was a better way. (See Update)

Comment: There's no built-in Rails method to do it. So, yeah, it might be a little "dirty".

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars, :reject_if => :any_invalid_bar?

  def any_invalid_bar?
    bars.any? &:invalid?
  end
```

This way validates each `Bar` with any validation you write in `Bar` before saving one `Foo`.